# how to deploy java web application to tomcat server using jenkins?

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

I am new to jenkins and tomcat server. 
I want to deploy java based web application on tomcat server.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Jenkins Deploy plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Just configure it with your servers information and it should be very straight forward to get it running.